# how can i make a hex string from integer value in Brightscright?

Tags: hex, decimal, roku, brightscript

I have written an Int 2 Hex function and was wondering if this is the best way

https://gist.github.com/kaayr1m/cacd3432b53fd854b0de

are there any other ways to do this?

```
' @param intValue positive integers from 0 onwards
function IntHexString(intValue as Integer) as String
 this = {}
 this.hexString = function(int) as String
    num = int/16.0
    remainder = (num mod 1) * 16.0
    result = fix(num)

    if remainder > 15
        hex = m.hexString(remainder)
    else
        hex = m.determineHex(remainder)
    end if

    if (result > 0) hex = m.hexString(result) + hex

    retun hex
 end function

 ' 0 --> 15
 this.determineHex = function(int) as String
    if int = 15 then return "F"
    if int = 14 then return "E"
    if int = 13 then return "D"
    if int = 12 then return "C"
    if int = 11 then return "B"
    if int = 11 then return "A"
    return int
 end function

 return this.hexString(intValue)
end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way - use [stri(val, radix)](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/BrightScript+Language+Reference#BrightScriptLanguageReference-812StrIvalueasIntegerradixasIntegerasString), like so:

```
BrightScript Debugger> ? &h12abcdef
 313249263
BrightScript Debugger> ? stri(313249263, 16)
12abcdef
```